# Contentful Backup Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs, contentful

I want to have an Azure Web Job that will run periodically and create Contentful Spaces backups in Azure Blob Storage.

I know that Contentful has their own CLI but not sure how can I run the CLI in an Azure Web Job using a .NET Core Console Application. Is that possible ?

I also found that they have their own API: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/ can I use this API to export Contentful data to a JSON file using .NET Core Console Application ?

PS: All the backups need to be done in a way that I can import the data again if necessary.

Comment: Hello, if the suggestion is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but suggestion for you.

I'm not familiar with Contentful, but for azure webjobs, there are 2 things you should remember:

1.If you're using .NET core console application, first, you can include all the logic in the console application and make sure it can work locally.

2.You should avoid [these limitations](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#general-sandbox-restrictions)(especially no UI operation) when publish to azure.

So in your .NET core console application, you can use [api](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/) or [sdk](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/net/tutorials/aspnet-core/) and make sure it works locally, then follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#webjob-types) to create the proper webjobs.

Hope it helps.